# Managing Transactions in Sequelize on NestJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js, nestjs

Ive integrated sequelize ORM in typescript. My database is connected successfully and even queries are working. Now i need to use transactions in my application but there's no clear documentation on how to make it work on nestjs.

Ive tried to integrate transactions through sequelize connection but it seems not to be working.

in my app.module ive created the sequelize configuration for root

```
@Module({


imports: [
    SequelizeModule.forRoot({
      dialect: 'mysql',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3306,
      username: Config.db_userName,
     // password: Config.db_password,
      database: "myDbName",
      autoLoadModels: true,
      models: []
    }),
  myModule],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
```

and in my service.ts file i have the following constructor trying to use this connection of sequelize

```
@InjectConnection()
private sequelize: Sequelize,
```

after that im trying to use this.sequelize.transaction its not giving me any error in code.. but after compiling. im receiving this error

```
this.sequelize.transaction() is not a function
```

Comment: Did you check what is stored in `this.sequelize`?

Comment: Its Empty object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently we don't need to inject connection for sequelize. It already have shared instance of sequelize.
We only have to use this 1 line in constructor.

```
private sequelize: Sequelize
```

remove the `injectConnection()` decorator.

Hope it helps someone in future

Answer (score 2):

I had an issue with:

```
private sequelize: Sequelize
```

And then I realized, I used wrong Sequelize import (from "sequelize"). This import worked for me.

```
import { Sequelize } from "sequelize-typescript"
```

Maybe it will help someone :)

Answer (score 0):

Whoever came here looking for an easy way to manage Sequelize transactions with method decorator (like @Transactional in Java Spring), you can try out this simple package I created - https://github.com/happnz/sequelize-transactional-decorator.

Easy setup with NestJS (also works without it).

1 Initialize CLS before app start

```
initSequelizeCLS();
```

2 Add module to initialize decorator:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    SequelizeModule.forRoot({
      ...
    }),
    SequelizeTransactionalModule.register(), // << this
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

3 Use Transactional annotation on class methods:

```
@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(Something)
    private readonly something: typeof Something,
    private readonly anotherService: AnotherService,
  ) {}

  @Transactional()
  async appMethod(): Promise<void> {
    await this.something.create({ message: 'hello' });
    await this.something.create({ message: 'world' });
    await this.anotherService.method(); // will use the same transaction by default, customizable with propagation option
  }
}
```